# Search post by categories Wordpress WP-API

Tags: php, json, wordpress, wp-api

I want to search posts by categories in the WP-API.

I know I can search posts by the attribute categories or filter[cat].

But the posts contains more than one category.

I tried to search like this:

```
{host}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=69&filter[cat]=[228,246,237]&per_page=50
```

or

```
{host}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=69&filter[cat]=228&filter[cat]=246&filter[cat]=237&per_page=50
```

or

```
{host}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=69&categories=246&categories=237&categories=228
```

This didn't work for me. It caused the search to look for the last attribute.

Any ideas?

This is the structure of Json response

```
{
    "id": 9333,
    "date": "2016-08-02T14:17:01",
    "date_gmt": "2016-08-02T12:17:01",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "{post}/?p=9333"
    },
    "modified": "2016-08-03T08:50:35",
    "modified_gmt": "2016-08-03T06:50:35",
    "slug": "{post}",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "{host}/{post}/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "{post}"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "{post}"
    },
    "excerpt": {
      "rendered": "{post}"
    },
    "author": 3,
    "featured_media": 0,
    "comment_status": "closed",
    "ping_status": "closed",
    "sticky": false,
    "format": "standard",
    "categories": [
      228,
      237,
      207,
      217,
      246,
      231,
      69,
      221,
      270,
      244
    ],
    "tags": [],
    "_links": []
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Change to English language - and wrap code in tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get posts from multiple categories, there are few solutions, depending from your needs.

In case when you want to get posts from category with ID = 1 OR category with ID = 2 use the following URL:

```
http://localhost/lifelog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[cat]=1,2
```

or:

```
http://localhost/lifelog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=1,2
```

For case when you want to get posts from category with ID = 1 AND category with ID = 2 you can use:

```
http://localhost/lifelog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category__and][]=1&filter[category__and][]=2
```

BUT - some filter values used in the filter array needs authenticated user with **edit_posts** privileges.

Fortunately, there is a more simple solution - WordPress supports links like:

```
http://example.com/category/test1+test2/
```

Under above URL you will get list of posts which are assigned to the test1 AND test2 categories. And in the REST API you can achieve the same behaviour with the following URL:

```
http://localhost/lifelog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category_name]=test1%2Btest2
```

Please remember that you have to replace the **+** sign into **%2B**.

Comment: I need get post with ID=1 and ID=2 etc...but ?filter[category__and][]=1&filter[category__and][]=2 not works for me

Comment: As I wrote "BUT - some filter values used in the filter array needs authenticated user with edit_posts privileges." - that's why I have suggested a solution with the plus sign.

Comment: Ok, perfect, the solution with plus sign works for me. Now, how do I do with the string that have spaces? Example = filter[category_name]=test 1%2Btest 2

Comment: test1 and test2 are the categories slugs, so you cannot use space in it - most probably for category called "test 1" you should use "test-1"

Comment: How to get categories from this type of api  ?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts .

Comment: The filter query param has been deprecated: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2799